Does "the note" refer to a piece of paper or a piece of writing?
This is the definition in Oxford dictionary

a note: [countable] a short piece of writing to help you remember
something

So, a note = a short piece of writing and "writing" is not paper but words or symbols.
Can I just say "I taped the note onto the table"?
Or do I have to say "I taped the small piece of paper containing the note onto the table" to to clear?

"I left the/a note [for you] on the table"

Downvoted for relying on a learner's dictionary only.  @Tom, you should graduate to standard dictionaries, since you often ask about the wording of a definition, and your rep here is not in the hundreds but over 20K. That said,  I was surprised that M-W didn't offer among its many definitions "a card or a piece of paper, usually smaller than standard letter size, with some handwriting on it, sometimes pinned to a dead body."
“Note.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/note. Accessed 30 Sep. 2024.

@TimR  Upvoted because the OP shared his research! And their questions are usually so detailed, well constructed and thought-out as well as being incredibly specific, we can tolerate a little carelessness. The fact that M-W does not  provide that detail of information that you expected, says something too, although it does say: 3 d 1: a short informal letter And... the Oxford Dictionary is for ADVANCED LEARNERs, which is exactly what the OP is.

@Mari-LouA You're missing the very point of my comment. A single learner's dictionary is not "research" when one is questioning its definition. One consults another dictionary. If still in doubt, ask here.

And "a short informal letter" is not "a short piece of writing to help you remember something".  You could be chasing your tail for quite a while if you take learner's definitions as gospel.

Actually the AL dictionary has this very definition 2.* a short informal letter* And the example:
She left a note for Ben on the kitchen table. Practically identical to my suggestion. The OP mentions taping a note ( a piece of paper) on a table. You can't scotch-tape a mental note, but you can use a Post-it in place of a short letter (or scrap of paper).

I feel like this question rests on a logical fallacy that's all too common when working with dictionaries; I guess it's a type of false equivalence? Or maybe just faulty generalization. "Word A is defined as meaning the same as Word B. The following is true of Word B. Therefore it must also be true of Word A." This is similar to "A platypus lays eggs. Animals that lay eggs are called birds. Therefore a platypus is a bird." Dictionaries must, by their nature, deal in generalization. When...

...When the dictionary says "Word A means Word B," of course it doesn't mean in a one-to-one way that is the same in all respects. And the simpler the definition (e.g. learners' dictionaries), the broader the generalizations. But I think you've worked with dictionaries long enough to know this, and to know that "a piece of writing cannot be a piece of paper" is a logical abuse of the dictionary, and to know that when you run up against such an apparent contradiction, you should read further and consult other sources.

You also probably know that many other words for "pieces of writing," like books, magazines, and letters, can refer to the intellectual content or to the physical object. Thus Moby Dick can be an experience that many generations have been traumatized by in high school, and a thing that falls out of your backpack. Voting to close because either the question is asked in bad faith, knowing there's no problem here, or is poorly researched.

@AndyBonner, book= a set of printed pages (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/book_1?q=book).

@AndyBonner, there is only 1 answer, which means most of you don't know the accurate answer. You just sit there and be judgmental about learners' questions. Or you can not find any source on the internet supporting your idea.

Oh for pete's sake, 1) read the whole page; once again, the next entry in the OLD references "book" as a work, though it doesn't explain too clearly, and 2) if you want to get specific, and your level of English supports it, move on to a non-learner's dictionary. Most mention the physical object, and I had to look through several to find an entry for the non-physical "piece of intellectual property" concept, but Collins collates several sources; scrolling down we find ...

... "a literary or scientific work, anthology, etc. so prepared, distinguished by length and form from a magazine, tract, etc." from Webster’s New World College Dictionary and "a written work or composition, such as a novel, technical manual, or dictionary" from Collins English Dictionary. For that matter if we look as far as Wikipedia we find "As a conceptual object, a book refers to a written work of substantial length, which may be distributed either physically or digitally as an ebook."

As to there being only one answer, it's bad form to both vote to close a question and answer it, and I agree with Astralbee's answer (as it mirrors what I said in a comment). If I seem annoyed, it's because this question seems like trolling, asking something you know not to be true just to provoke argument, and that's not very nice.

If a piece of paper has writing on it then it's common to refer to it as what it is - a note, a letter, a script, an invoice etc. "A piece of paper containing a note" is excessively long and feels clunky. It could also be misleading - for example, you can put a letter or a note into an envelope, and the envelope "contains" the note.

Content Vs medium. When Queen Victoria was arriving in Dublin on an official tour, she asked what all those pieces of paper floating in the River Liffey were. Nobody wanted to tell her until the Duke of Wellington said 'They are notices, ma'am, that bathing is forbidden'.

I would argue this extends to just about all writing, and even other forms of human communication and creativity. "Beethoven's 5th" is both the manuscript pages, and the non-physical intellectual content of the composition, and the aural reality of a live performance, and the recording of such a performance on physical medium. Ditto Monet's water lilies, the/a Bible, and Deep Impact.
